# How to enforce version in `pyproject.toml` for package A to be same as packabe B while version of package B is variable?

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I want to enforce version for package A to be same as version for package B, but version for package B has more slack with `package-b>=0.0.1`

In particular, it's about jax and jaxlib. According to this [issue](https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/14036). Both need to have the same version, but which version is not of importance.

Comment: One option would be to create a "meta package" C that depends on fixed versions of A and B.

Comment: Specific to jax, it looks like jax [already provides an extra](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/main/setup.py#L73) that fixes the version of jaxlib. Does installing jax as `pip install jax[minimum-jaxlib]` help?

Comment: Looks good! I am specifying jax and jaxlib for my own package in `pyproject.toml`.
How would I specify those install options in `pyproject.toml` @Brian?

Comment: It you're using setuptools as your build system, I believe using `"jax[minimum-jaxlib]"` in `dependencies` would do the trick.

Comment: @Brian61354270 could you give some reference or explanation for this? thanks